# Does webpack code splitting work in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webpack, code-splitting

I am using in a web application [`react-router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/).

When using `import 'lodash'` I import the whole `lodash` lib in my project.

Code splitting is about using an `async` import using `import().then()` to dynamically load chunk while the application is running.

Read about [code splitting in react-router/web](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/code-splitting).

For example: `function atRuntime() { import('lodash').then(() => {});}`

This will import the library at runtime with an ajax request so it is not bundled in the `main.js`.

I'd like to recycle my code between web and native and we use a lot of code splitting for each page change.

My app has two main parts and some user will only visit one part so they don't need all user authenticated part.

I expect to be able to use tree shaking during react-native, but it is missing in [react-router/native](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/guides/quick-start) documentation.

What's react-native opinion about code splitting?

Comment: I ended up using code splitting only for `.web.js` route.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use webpack, you can try with haul https://github.com/callstack/haul

but i highly recommend this implementation without webpack -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bundle-splitter

Comment: Why do you **highly** recommend this implementation without Webpack ?